# Setting the scope of this

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to learn to work in a more object oriented way in javascript using the jQuery librari 1.9.I am at a point in a small project where I have to change the scope of the this object.Here is my html:

```
<div id="contact">
<h2>Contact Me</h2>
<form action="#">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input name="name" id="name">
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="email">Email Address: </label>
            <input name="email" id="email">
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="comments">What's Up?</label>
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And here is my javascript

```
var contactForm = {
    contact : $('div#contact'),

    init : function(){
        this.contact.hide();
        $('<button></button>' , { 
            text : "Display Contact"
        }).insertAfter('article')
          .on('click' , this.show);
    },

    show : function(){
       $.proxy(contactForm , this)
       this.contact.slideDown();

    }
};

contactForm.init();
```

The problem is at my show method.I know that I can set the scop of "this" using $.proxy().But I must be doing it wrong because even after settign $.proxy , the "this" keyword still refers to the button.

How can I make this "this" keyword refer to the "contactForm" object

Comment: Hi, I added more explanations with a working copy of your code using proxy. please review it again. http://jsfiddle.net/Brnv2/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
.on('click', $.proxy(this.show, this));
```

And show:

```
show: function() {
   this.contact.slideDown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

reading the documentation about proxy, it will not change the "this" context in the current method. The signature for proxy is `$.proxy( myFunction, thisVar )` which means that proxy will return the function `myFunction` and when it executes `myFunction` the this value will refer to `thisVar`.

Does this resolve your problem?

this means that you want to change your show function to something like :

```
show : function(){
   $.proxy( function(){ this.slideDown() }, contactForm )();

}
```

Here is a simple example of how it works

```
 f = $.proxy( function(){ console.log(this.msg); } , { msg: "hello world" });
 f(); // ==> should log to console "hello world"
```

Here is a [fiddle to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/uZB3A/3/)

You can also pass parameters to the function. For example:

```
 f = $.proxy( function(msg){ console.log([this,msg]); }, { topic:"my topic" } )
 f("hello world");
```

see a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BKage/) to see this in action too.

Last but not least, this is a [fiddle with your code working like I suggested.](http://jsfiddle.net/Brnv2/4/)

Comment: I have tryed this but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
.on('click' , this.show)
```

although this refers to `this.show`, it doesn't set the context to `this` when `show` is subsequently invoked as an event handler.  You've got a function reference, but it ends up detached from the object which originally contained it.

You should use:

```
.on('click', $.proxy(this.show, this))
```

and remove the `$.proxy` call from within `.show`

Note that `$.proxy()` is intended to *return* a new function reference which when called will always have the given context.  It does nothing to the *current* function's context.